# Refencing a file in a parent directory

Tags: html, directory

This probably a silly question but,
I have a project set up on my Desktop at:
**~/Desktop/composer/**
Inside this directory I have my folders:
**css** and **templates**
Inside my templates folder I have my **index.html** file, and I need to reference my css file in my css folder, but I can figure out how
I have tried: 
**/../css/style.css** and **/../../css/style.css**, but neither of them work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the leading `/`, since it denotes the root of your filesystem.  Try `../css/style.css`.